# How to create a route Path from a Json Array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, data-structures

I have a array consist some random city names , Another Array of json object which consist the Source and Destination of Individual cities , But this route array of individual cities are not in a sequence. I need to make it in a sequence in order they visited , I am unable to make the logic .. please help ..

Array of Cities (Dynamic Size):

```
var CITIES = ["PARIS","LONDON","DELHI","SINGAPORE","DUBAI"]
```

Json Array of Route (In Random Sequence) :

```js
var CITY_ROUTE = {"ROUTE":[
{"CURRENT_CITY":"PARIS","NEXT_CITY":"LONDON","PREVIOUS_CITY":"DUBAI",},
{"CURRENT_CITY":"DELHI","NEXT_CITY":"SINGAPORE","PREVIOUS_CITY":"LONDON"},
{"CURRENT_CITY":"LONDON","NEXT_CITY":"DELHI","PREVIOUS_CITY":"PARIS"},
{"CURRENT_CITY":"SINGAPORE","NEXT_CITY":"","PREVIOUS_CITY":"DELHI"},
{"CURRENT_CITY":"DUBAI","NEXT_CITY":"PARIS","PREVIOUS_CITY":""}
]};

/Required to Rearange the Json Object in Visiting sequence where Starting City will have null PREVIOUS_CITY value and Last City will have null  NEXT_CITY Value/


var CITY_ROUTE_IN_SEQUENCE = {"ROUTE":[
{"CURRENT_CITY":"DUBAI","NEXT_CITY":"PARIS","PREVIOUS_CITY":""}
{"CURRENT_CITY":"PARIS","NEXT_CITY":"LONDON","PREVIOUS_CITY":"DUBAI",},
{"CURRENT_CITY":"LONDON","NEXT_CITY":"DELHI","PREVIOUS_CITY":"PARIS"},
{"CURRENT_CITY":"DELHI","NEXT_CITY":"SINGAPORE","PREVIOUS_CITY":"LONDON"},
{"CURRENT_CITY":"SINGAPORE","NEXT_CITY":"","PREVIOUS_CITY":"DELHI"}
]};
```

Comment: Well, it seems like the entry that has an empty `PREVIOUS_CITY` property needs to be first. Then you can simply chain them together based on `NEXT_CITY`. (If the data might have cycles, that's a harder problem, but I don't see that here.)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var CITY_ROUTE = {
    "ROUTE": [
        {"CURRENT_CITY":"PARIS","NEXT_CITY":"LONDON","PREVIOUS_CITY":"DUBAI",},
        {"CURRENT_CITY":"DELHI","NEXT_CITY":"SINGAPORE","PREVIOUS_CITY":"LONDON"},
        {"CURRENT_CITY":"LONDON","NEXT_CITY":"DELHI","PREVIOUS_CITY":"PARIS"},
        {"CURRENT_CITY":"SINGAPORE","NEXT_CITY":"","PREVIOUS_CITY":"DELHI"},
        {"CURRENT_CITY":"DUBAI","NEXT_CITY":"PARIS","PREVIOUS_CITY":""}
    ]
};

var map = {};
var point = '';
CITY_ROUTE.ROUTE.forEach(r => {
    map[r.CURRENT_CITY] = r;
    if (!r.PREVIOUS_CITY) {
        point = r.CURRENT_CITY;
    }
});

CITY_ROUTE.ROUTE = [];
while(point) {
    CITY_ROUTE.ROUTE.push(map[point]);
    point = map[point].NEXT_CITY;
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(CITY_ROUTE));
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you could try something of form Linked List.. The first node will contain the city having PREVIOUS_CITY null and the last node will have the NEXT_CITY null.. then after Arraging them in a linked list.. you could easily print them..

1st node Dubai -> 2nd Paris -> 3rd London -> 4th Delhi -> 5th Singapore

In case you need to check for the previous city.. you can use doubly linked list..
There is a resource telling you how to implement linked lists in JS

http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/data-structures-with-javascript-singly-linked-list-and-doubly-linked-list--cms-23392

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @TedHopp ... It's not efficient but doing the JOB ..

```js
var SortedArray=[];
var CITY_ROUTE = {"ROUTE":[
{"CURRENT_CITY":"PARIS","NEXT_CITY":"LONDON","PREVIOUS_CITY":"DUBAI",},
{"CURRENT_CITY":"DELHI","NEXT_CITY":"SINGAPORE","PREVIOUS_CITY":"LONDON"},
{"CURRENT_CITY":"LONDON","NEXT_CITY":"DELHI","PREVIOUS_CITY":"PARIS"},
{"CURRENT_CITY":"SINGAPORE","NEXT_CITY":"","PREVIOUS_CITY":"DELHI"},
{"CURRENT_CITY":"DUBAI","NEXT_CITY":"PARIS","PREVIOUS_CITY":""}
]};

for(var index in CITY_ROUTE.ROUTE)
{
 if(CITY_ROUTE.ROUTE[index].PREVIOUS_CITY == "")
  {
  var NextCity = CITY_ROUTE.ROUTE[index].NEXT_CITY;
  SortedArray.push(CITY_ROUTE.ROUTE[index])
  CITY_ROUTE.ROUTE.splice(index,1);
    while(CITY_ROUTE.ROUTE.length>0)
    {
      for(var i in CITY_ROUTE.ROUTE)
    {
         if(CITY_ROUTE.ROUTE[i].CURRENT_CITY === NextCity)
          {
          SortedArray.push(CITY_ROUTE.ROUTE[i])
          NextCity = CITY_ROUTE.ROUTE[i].NEXT_CITY;
          CITY_ROUTE.ROUTE.splice(i,1);
          }
        }   
    }
  }
}
console.log(SortedArray.length)
console.log(CITY_ROUTE.ROUTE.push(SortedArray))
console.log(JSON.stringify(CITY_ROUTE.ROUTE))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
   $.ajax({

```
type: "POST",
url: "<?php print $this->Url ?>index.php/employee/addemployee/viewrole,//your URL

data: {'CITY_ROUTE': CITY_ROUTE,'CITY_ROUTE_IN_SEQUENCE',CITY_ROUTE_IN_SEQUENCE},
success: function (response) {
var data = jQuery.parseJSON(response);

}

                                                                        }
                                                                    });
```